# Difference between boolean evaluation and !empty in PHP

Tags: php, boolean

In PHP, what is the difference between:

```
if($might_not_be_set) doStuff();
```

and:

```
if(!empty($might_not_be_set)) doStuff();
```

The former approach clutters the Apache logs with undefined variable notices, but I don't see the reason to not use it - what does it do differently?

PS. I don't want to use `isset()` - evaluating as a boolean is exactly what I want.

Comment: But that's exactly its purpose. Leave the error reporting to PHP for variables whose absence you want to be logged. Use isset/empty for things you'd absolutely never care about.

Comment: manual knows all: http://nz.php.net/manual/en/types.comparisons.php

Comment: @Dagon if you look at that table you linked to you'll see that the `empty()` section is exactly inverse of the `Boolean: if ($x)` section - meaning there supposedly is no difference. And the manual does not tell me why "Simply doing if ($x) while $x is undefined will generate an error of level E_NOTICE" - I want to know why :)

Comment: Because in general, if you access variables that don't exist, you deserve to get yelled at. Why does PHP need justification for doing the reasonable thing for once?

Comment: Don't see why this question was downvoted

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You said it yourself: the first method clutters the logs with warnings about undeclared variables. Both methods are functionally equivalent, but it never hurts to be explicit. I would go with the !empty() because it is both explicit and avoids the clutter.

Answer (score 2):

empty() will evaluate a zero length string or NULL to TRUE while any longer string (or integer or boolean) will be FALSE. Therefore, your !empty() will just make sure that there is *some* value in there, not necessarily the one you want..

For example, an empty() check of the *strings* 1, false, and true all evaluate to FALSE while a *string* of 0 will evaluate to TRUE.

I suggest that whatever you use, you should be painfully explicit for the next guy on what you are/aren't expecting.. even if that's just you six months from now.

Here's a detailed comparison:
http://php.net/manual/en/types.comparisons.php

Answer (score 1):

`empty()` determine whether a variable is considered to be empty. A variable is considered empty if it does not exist or if its value equals FALSE. **empty() does not generate a warning if the variable does not exist**.

http://php.net/manual/en/function.empty.php

Comment: I'm asking what the difference is - evaluating like I did in my first example seems to achieve the same effect.